# Why can't I override the default argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following code:

```
import pickle

def open_file(fname, fname1 = None):
    # returns a new OPEN file
    if fname1:
        while fname == fname1:
            f_name = input("File already open, filename: ")
    f = None
    while not f:
        try:
            f = open(fname, "rb")
        except IOError:
            fname = input("File not found, filename: ")
    print(fname, "open")
    return f

def get_2cubes():
    a_name = input("\nWhat is the name of the first cube's file? ")
    a_file = open_file(a_name)
    #a_cube = pickle.load(a_file)
    a_file.close()

    b_name = input("\nWhat is the name of the second cube's file? ")
    b_file = open_file(b_name, a_name)
    #b_cube = pickle.load(b_file)
    b_file.close()
    #return a_cube, b_cube

get_2cubes()
```

The code is meant to open a second file only if it's not the first file.

The first file's name is represented by `fname1` in open_file(). If the name of the second file (`b_name` in this case) matches that of the first file the user will be prompted to enter a new name.

I supplied a default argument of `None` for the `fname1` parameter because the function will sometimes be used only for opening one file and not for also comparing it to another file. However, I can't seem to override the default argument.

The `a_name` variable from the 7th line of `get_2cubes` is not being recognized by the `if fname1:` condition in `open_file`, and as a result I can open the same file twice. How would I correct this?

Comment: `fname1 = input("File already open, filename: ")`

Comment: What Ashwini means is that, if your `if` worked and the names were equal, then you'd be having an infinite `while` loop, because you're assigning to the variable `f_name` and checking equality on `fname` and `fname1`.

Comment: But it would only be infinite if the user kept on trying to give the second file the same name as the first.

Comment: Nope. You're not updating neither `fname` nor `fname1`, so they'll be equal forever, until CTRL+C do them apart.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your `open_file` function and seeing what it is doing?

Comment: I haven't got round to using the Python debugger yet.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use `raw_input`. Otherwise the text entered will treated as a variable name, and therefore will equal to `None`. (Unless you're on Python 3)

Comment: Yup, I figured it after from the `print()` even tho' coming from Java I always use parentheses in both v2 and v3. P.S. I tried your code and it seems to work fine, after changing `f_name` to `fname1` as suggested in the comment.

Comment: What about the other three references to fname in open_file()?

Comment: Well, they seem fine from a "formal correctness" point of view.

Comment: I've corrected open_file(): it should return f and fname; new_a_name is then the second argument in the second open_file() call; the first while loop is moved inside the second while loop without the 'if fname1' clause; and the f_name typo is corrected.